# Password authentication failed: loading a csv into a PostgreSQL database with SQLAlchemy

Tags: database, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to load a csv into a PostgreSQL database with SQLAlchemy but I get the following error:

```
OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "localhost" 
(::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "jim"
```

How do I fix the password authentication? Here is the code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine 
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Date, Float

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://jim:password@localhost:5432/travel')
session = Session(engine)

Base = declarative_base()


class travel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'travel_full'
    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    year = Column(Date)
    quarter = Column(Integer)
    mode = Column(String(55))
    country = Column(String(55))
    purpose = Column(String(55))

csv = 'travel.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(csv)
df.to_sql(con=engine, index_label='id', name=travel.__tablename__, if_exists='replace')
```

Comment: Use the correct password? Because the combination username/password that you use right now, is not valid for this database server.

Comment: Isn't it set using `create_engine()`? So it this case, isn't it the part of the string 'jim:password'?

Comment: Yes it is set, the error is telling you it is the wrong one. So either the password is wrong or you are connecting to the wrong database.

Comment: Does that connect string work when doing things other than loading a csv?

Comment: Are there any special characters in the password?  If so it may need to be url-encoded.

Comment: No, I want the password to be just "password". I'm missing something obvious here. I thought this line of code connects sets the password and connects you to the database 

`engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://jim:password@localhost:5432/travel')`

Comment: Ok I think I know where I'm going wrong - I'm expecting Postgresql to act like SQLite - i.e. create a file locally, when in actual fact it's a server that I need to set up